# Stacked percent bar in a spark line grid for Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to modify the [Highcharts spark line example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/sparkline) at http://jsfiddle.net/o78jnpcz/, such that the charts are just a horizontal stacked percentage bar instead of area chart.

If I just change the chart type to 'bar' and add the `bar : { stacking : 'percent' }` markup to `plotOptions` (or even stacking normal), this only results in multiple horizontal bars instead of a single stacked bar.

This looks like a simple issue of not preprocessing data properly, but I'm new to Highcharts and haven't been able to figure it out for a while. How can I get it to display a stacked bar view? Additionally, how to add shared click handlers for the bar (shared between the sections, and can identify each different chart in the grid).

Example of a cell:

[image: Stacked percent bar in grid]

Since the data for Alabama in the example is 71, 78, 39, 66; this should display a single stacked bar all the way to the end (percent stacking) with section lengths in the right ratio.

Edit:

Took me some time to figure out what I wanted, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p263pkef/) with my changes if anyone is interested in something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add extra serie and enable `stacking option`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cmozvokp/

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the data in multiple sections, but rather show all of it in a single percent bar - updated the question to show an example of what the cell content should look like.

Comment: The answer is still relevant. Each section in a stacked bar needs to be a different series.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/96uhd8wz/